# If I stake 1000 EOS for cpu and 1000 for net? How much do I get after 10 days?

Tags: cpu, net, stake

If I staked the following to:

- 1000 eos to cpu
- 1000 eos to net

How much will I have staked by 10 days?

And do I keep these cpu and net resources forever if I never use it? Or does it expire?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In POS  you may get passive income(LISK) what you have in your wallet,but in DPOS you don`t instead you vote with your tokens to elect bp,who intern gives free tx and other resources 

You can get REX token for leasing your EOS tokens 30 days ,you can get passive income from it ,
 
Even you own tokens at stake if you dont use for 3yr, you are going to be blocked or removed

Comment: " Even you own tokens at stake if you dont use for 3yr, you are going to be blocked or removed" <- this is not true; nothing happens after 3 years. also i think op asks about how much resources they get not how much money

Comment: @confused00 , As per the EOS constitution Article 15, In activity of account for 3yr will put account for auction, not just name but  `the ownership`. (change in keys) https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8s5sjx/dans_interpretation_of_article_xv/

Comment: sorry, "nothing happens after 3 years" was overly decisive. article xv exists in the interim constitution that hasn't been voted on yet, but there's a referendum where these things shall be voted on by the community

Comment: No mention,The god thing about EOS constitutions is proposals,community can decide and vote for good.Even DAN has no control to implement without comminty approval,unlike proprietary companies.Where they are law makers.